# How can I get bot to auto-run at a certain time, or when a certain condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, bots

I'm building a basic Instagram bot, and it got me wondering, how could I get to auto-run at a certain time, or when a certain condition is satisfied (eg. when there's a new file in a folder)?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: What you need is a library called Apscheduler: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a while loop and check your condition each time, suggest you to put some kind of sleep (eg. `asynco.sleep()` or `time.sleep()`) and if the condition is true then run the bot